# Handling missing key:values from json in c#

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a json string returned from an api. Here are the classes;

```
namespace APItest
{
public class Rootobject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
}

    public class Result
    {
        public Referral referral { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public Closing closing { get; set; }
    }

    public class Referral
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? created_on { get; set; }
        public DateTime? accepted_on { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Closing
    {
        public DateTime? date { get; set; }
        public int? home_price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Eventually I need to pass these values to a SQL stored procedure. The problem I'm having is not all key value pairs exist all the time. If the referral hasn't been accepted, the referral.accepted_on key and value don't exist in the string. If there is no closing, the entire closing class will be missing.

I've tried

```
var deserializedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);
            var referralFields = deserializedJson.results.Select(i => new 
            { 
                i.referral.id, 
                i.referral.created_on,
                i.referral.accepted_on,

                i.customer.firstname,
                i.customer.lastname,
                i.customer.email,
                i.customer.phone,

                i.closing.date,
                i.closing.home_price
            
            }).ToList();

            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("uspDwellfulReferralsInsert", Conn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Conn.Open();

            foreach (var field in referralFields)
            {

                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReferralId", field.id));

                if (field.created_on != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReferralCreatedOn", field.created_on));
                }

                if (field.accepted_on != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReferralAcceptedOn", field.accepted_on));
                }
                if (field.firstname != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerFirstName", field.firstname));
                }

                if (field.lastname != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerLastName", field.lastname));
                }

                if (field.email != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerEmail", field.email));
                }

                if (field.phone != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerPhone", field.phone));
                }

                if (field.date != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClosingDate", field.date));
                }

                if (field.home_price != null)
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClosingHomePrice", field.home_price));
                }

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            
            Conn.Close();
}
```

This works when all key value pairs are present, but fails when some are missing. I won't go through the numerous things I've tried, but I think I've managed to generate every error message known to man. Nothing I've tried works. How do you account for missing pairs, or an entire missing class?

Comment: "How do you account for missing pairs, or an entire missing class?" You should explain us how it could be arranged , what you tried and what is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason why you use the linq method to retrieve properties from a list to generate a new list? You can simplify your code by iterating on the main *results* property of the object:

```
        var deserializedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);

        foreach (var obj in deserializedJson.results)
        {
            if(obj.referral.created_on != null)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReferralCreatedOn", obj.referral.created_on));
            }
            if (obj.referral.accepted_on != null)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReferralAcceptedOn", obj.referral.accepted_on));
            }
            if (obj.customer.firstname != null)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerFirstName", obj.customer.firstname));
            }
            // rest of checks
        }
```

Comment: Thanks tlucian, that worked! I had it that way because I'm new to c# and what little I know I learned here or Googling various other sites. Sometime what worked in one situation, doesn't work in another.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass these values to a SQL stored procedure. The problem I'm having is not all key value pairs exist all the time.

Why not, in the database, create a User Defined Table Type which can have each of the models as sub User Defined Table types. Then adjust sproc to instead take the top level table type instead.

*To do this the code will need to create a user defined table type, which is like the `SqlParameter` processing you do now.*

> This works when all key value pairs are present, but fails when some are missing.

Using User Defined Table types comes into the sproc as individual tables (1-N); if there is a missing sub table, the sproc should be able to handle that indirectly or directly if need be.

---

The added benefit of using Table Types is that the `Merge` statement can handle insert/updates quite easily, since the data is already in tables instead of scalars; sweet.